# How do I fix "using own name in class file is not allowed" error Godot GD Script

Tags: godot, gdscript

How do I fix the using own name in class file is not allowed error?

```
class_name Player
var player = Player.new() # error line


var player_seed= ""
func _on_Button_pressed():
    var new_seed = int($ColorRect/LineEdit.text)
    player.player_seed = new_seed
```

Comment: Your code creates an infinite loop by creating a new instance of player which on creation creates a new instance of player, which on creation creates a new instance ... 

What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Creating a new object of the class within the class itself really doesn't do you any good, you can directly write `player_seed = new_seed` or use `self.player_seed = new_seed`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easist fix for this error is simply removing the variable, and replace all "Player" instances with self.

```
class_name Player

var player_seed= ""
func _on_Button_pressed():
    var new_seed = int($ColorRect/LineEdit.text)
    self.player_seed = new_seed
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use `class_name` you are giving a name to the class of the script. This class has everything inside the script. Which in this cases includes a variable initialized by creating a new instance of the same class.

That, as observed, does not work. If it did, the object would create an object of your class which creates and object of your which creates an object of your class which creates an object of your class which creates an object of your class… At infinitum. Well, until it runs out of memory actually.

As pointed out in comments, you can directly use your object. Like this:

```
class_name Player

var player_seed= ""
func _on_Button_pressed():
    var new_seed = int($ColorRect/LineEdit.text)
    player_seed = new_seed
```

Also, by the way, `self` is a reference to it. So this also works:

```
class_name Player

var player_seed= ""
func _on_Button_pressed():
    var new_seed = int($ColorRect/LineEdit.text)
    self.player_seed = new_seed
```

In these case, these are equivalent. *In general they differ in that by not using `self` it would bypass any property setters. But there aren't property setters, they are the same.*

---

Now, it is possible you meant something different:

```
var player = Player.new()

func _on_Button_pressed():
    var new_seed = int($ColorRect/LineEdit.text)
    player.player_seed = new_seed

class Player
    var player_seed= ""
```

Here we are leaving the class of the script anonymous (it does not have `class_name`), and it has a nested class called `Player`. Of which the script creates an instance.

If you need this Player class elsewhere, then perhaps it is wise to move it to a separate script:

Your first script would look like this:

```
var player = Player.new()

func _on_Button_pressed():
    var new_seed = int($ColorRect/LineEdit.text)
    player.player_seed = new_seed
```

And then you would have a second script with this code:

```
class_name Player

var player_seed= ""
```

Ultimately, every situation where you need to reference the same class can be addressed by similar means. Where one script is responsible creating the instances of the other. However, the details will vary from case to case.